# TypeError: $(...).autoabbr is not a function even when the function is there

Tags: highlight, glossary

I am trying to use autoabbr.js from github to automatically highlight predefined words on any page and show their definition on hover. I believe I did everything right but it is not working.

I get the error: `TypeError: $(...).autoabbr is not a function`

Here is the codepen. https://codepen.io/amitkapoor/pen/wvKRMdg

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this should be a simple one, your last line is:

```
})(jquery);
```

Try changing `jquery` to `jQuery`, with a capital-Q.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that in my project, I had this statement:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var jQuery_theme = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

As soon as I disabled it, error gone. But because I wanted this, I moved my scripts post this statement and they work now. But now, the script is working only on the hardcoded text and not dynamically generated content. It must be $ playing me again....

Thanks!

And yes, I did change jquery to JQuery later.